# Strange problem with VLC

Tags: video, vlc

I don't know what has happened to VLC, suddenly one day it started playing videos in full-screen mode with a the bottom part of video black! while it works fine in normal mode.

Also the mouse pointer doesn't show while I'm hovering it over the video part, rest everywhere else it works fine! also in the bottom black part of the video in full-screen mode it works fine!

Please help me!

[image: video in normal mode]

[image: video in full-screen mode]

```
VLC version: 2.2.1 Weatherwax buildd@lgw01-18.buildd August 23 2015 19:27:18
```

**Edit 1**: I just installed VLC 3.0.0-git Vetinari buildd@icy01-34.buildd Jan 25 2016 06:16:39 and the problem persists!

**Edit 2**: as suggested by andrew.46 I ran both commands and the results were:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

**Edit 3**: the pointer is working in full-screen now, also I see the full-screen controls now which were unavailable earlier but the original full-screen problem of bottom black screen continues!

**Edit 4**: I don't know what happened, it started playing videos in full-screen properly!
*PS. I didn't reboot!*

**Edit 5**: It started happening again since next day from which *edit 4* was posted. Please help. None of the answers posted below helped.

Comment: Sorry to ask a really obvious questions, please forgive me in advance, "you have rebooted" or in [British, "have you tried turning it off and then turning it on again"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)

Comment: yes, I have! I even completely reinstalled VLC 3 times!

Comment: In VLC Tools > Preferences > Video > Output change the Default to X11, save and restart vlc.

Comment: Have other packages been installed/upgraded, such as graphics drivers?

Comment: @DnrDevil yes I did! didn't help.

Comment: @KenSharp I don't think so, or maybe yes and I didn't pay attention to what was being upgraded.

Comment: There is a setting that might be worth looking at: when the video is playing right click on the video screen and select: Video --> Always Fit Window

Comment: @andrew.46 it's already checked.

Comment: @JimLohse lol that video! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was kubuntu backports ppa (ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports) that was causing this issue! now that it's gone everything is back to normal!

though I still don't know what caused this, if anyone knows about it please enlighten me!

Comment: kubuntu backports ppa (ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports) ?

Comment: @ElderGeek yes that's what I wrote!

Comment: What he meant to say was: Which package of that PPA exactly?

Comment: Actually what I meant to indicate is that clearly you do know what caused this at least in part. It would seem that with ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports enabled you had the problems you stated.

Comment: @ElderGeek no, I don't know the exact package that caused this problem! but I used it for amarok and then there were many side packages that were auto installed!

Comment: dpkg.log tracks what has been installed.  An analysis of the content of that file along with a review of the dependencies for vlc and amarok might be helpful in solving your mystery.  I would guess that an older version of something that both amarok and vlc require that got pulled in through backports likely caused the issue. I'm glad you got it resolved.

Comment: yeah pretty much what seem to have happened!
and as I have fresh installed Ubuntu Gnome over Unity so I don't think logs would be preserved.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you uninstall and then reinstall vlc the configuration file can linger. This often gives unpredictable results. To eliminate this as a problem run the following 2 commands:

```
vlc --reset-config
vlc --reset-plugins-cache
```

This will reset you vlc configuration to the vlc defaults as well as resetting your plugins cache and may be enough to bring vlc back to life...