# VLC not showing entire screen

Tags: video, vlc, video-player

When I switch to full screen mode, the bottom quarter of the screen becomes black. Any idea on how I could fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Im using ubuntu 15.10.

EDIT:

[Strange problem with VLC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725679/strange-problem-with-vlc?rq=1)

The question in the link above describes almost EXACTLY what happened to me. But the given solution doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have only a single monitor on your computer, or more than one?

Comment: Just one monitor.